# Count specific string with a 1 point value if greater than 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I found a similar thread however assigning point values is where it did not work. So essentially I have an excel sheet that shows this:
[image]

I need to had a formula that will count the 'A's in a row and if the value is greater than two, i need it to count as 1 point. The end goal is to have a count of all rows that have 2 or more 'A's.The issue i am running into is how to assign point values with a true or false statement.

Keep in mind, in case you have a better way, there are roughly 90 pages of these and a line may or may not contain other works and or phrases. This is the only box with just an 'A'. I need to count each page separately.

Oh and a good way to stop the range search is there is normally 5 blank rows before the next page.

Comment: `=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1, "A")>2,1,0)` (adjusting the range as necessary) should do the job. Of course, there's no reason to assign a point value to do what you describe: you could simply use `=COUNTIF(A1:Z1, "A")>2` and then filter on `TRUE`.

Comment: This is not working. I tried both with proper ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"*A*")+COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"*a*")>2,1,"")
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you Roger.

Comment: If for example, i want the formula to appear blank (not a 1 point value) if a specific cell has any text or value, how can i add that to this formula?

Comment: @jallington : I am not sure that I understand your intent. I assume that you want the formula to not be applied if a "specific cell" within the row is blank. If so,  IF(ISBLANK(T1),"",IF(COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"*A*")+COUNTIF(A1:Z1,"*a*")>2,1,"")) where T1 is the blank cell.

Comment: H: That is what i am trying to achieve however, this formula also returns an error and highlights the 2 as well. That seems to be the issue.

Comment: @jallington : =IF(ISBLANK(E1),IF(COUNTIF(A1:G1,"*A*")+COUNTIF(A1:G1,"*a*")>1,1,""),"")    I had the logic reversed earlier.

Comment: @jallington : Finally ...  =IF(ISBLANK(E1),IF((COUNTIF(A1:G1,"*A*")+COUNTIF(A1:G1,"*a*"))>1,1,""),"")

Comment: You got it! This is going to save us hours! Thank you!